# Embedding an activity onto another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a couple of activities in which an image has to be downloaded and displayed. The image is downloaded from a URL into the internal storage, scaled down, and then displayed.

Is there any way to avoid duplicating the same code in multiple activities? Can i create one activity that contains all the code, and maybe I pass the URL as an Intent Extra. (please note that all the HTTP methods are already in a separate class, it is the UI functions like calculating image aspect ratio and assigning height and width to the image layout that i dont want to repeate)

What i am looking is not a Dialog activity. Something like embedding the image activity's UI onto the calling activity's UI.

Comment: I suspect you're mixing up some terminology. Activities aren't embedded into layouts, they describe how to interact with a particular screen. I suspect what you want is a custom image **view**, not a custom activity. Or otherwise please describe more what kind of code it is you're trying to avoid duplication of.

Comment: and i suspect he has a bit of trouble understanding general object oriented programming. (no offence!) All the work can be done in some thread/object and only one activity is needed to interact with the user.

Comment: I have a list of methods that i perform for displaying an image. Download > Check response > if response is ok then scale down image and display it, otherwise display default image > hide progress bars.
I am looking for a way to avoid duplicating all this code, and I believe i cant use a separate class since im performing UI functions  also. (i've edited my question also). thanks

Comment: Well, to prevent writing the same code twice, you could create abstract Activity class called ImageActivity, and give it the methods you use more than once.. Then just extend the ImageActivity class when you need those methods in an activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the code to download and scale the image into a utility class that all the activities can call using AsyncTasks. the you can display it in onPostExecute.